# How do I generate a grid where each cell is equal to 500 px at 1:250k scale?

Tags: extents, scale, pixel, scale-factor

I worked this out once but I forgot how I did it. Somehow the grid size created a whole number of cells.

I have a map with the following extents:

xmin = -20037508.3427892439067364

xmax = 20037508.3427892439067364

ymin = -20037508.3427892439067364

ymax = 20037508.3427892439067364

I want to generate a grid where each cell is 500 by 500 pixels (at 1:250,000 scale). How do I convert the extent values from metres to pixels (at 1:250,000 scale)?

Comment: Your ymax abd ymin values are the same... I think something is wrong there - we would also need to know the unit of the coordinates to have any idea of the factors needed (you can edit the question)

Comment: That was a typo. I've corrected it now. The extents are in metres as stated.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?